# How to use `FindResourceEx()` and `LoadResource()` to load a new menu?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am developing a multilingual Win32 program in C using the Windows API. It will allow the user to choose the language of the interface. In accordance to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx), I need to use [`FindResourceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [`LoadResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and **not** the unreliable [`SetThreadLocale()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My problem is: I do not know how to load the menu from the resources.

Considering the example code below, how should it be modified to load and update the menu?

```c
HMENU hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
SetMenu(hWnd, NULL);
DestroyMenu(hMenu);

HRSRC rcMenu = FindResourceEx(NULL, RT_MENU, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MENU),
    MAKELANGID(LANG_AFRIKAANS, SUBLANG_AFRIKAANS_SOUTH_AFRICA));

hMenu = LoadResource(NULL, rcMenu); /* ??? HGLOBAL used as a HANDLE? */
SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
```

Comment: What we do on our product team:  Each language in it's own resource DLL.    Then at runtime, we just load the resource DLL that matches the desired user language.  Such that we can just call `LoadMenu` directly without having to any special handling.   Non-localized resources such as images and icons just stay in the EXE.  Would you be interested in a solution along those lines?

Comment: @selbie Yes I am; especially if it allows the language to be changed at any time during runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative solution suggested in the commands (separate DLL resource files per-language) is a good option and one we use ourselves. However to answer your question:

The `LoadMenuIndirect()` function lets you create a menu (user object) from a resource template. It's the template that's loaded from resources.

For example (no error checking),

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResourceEx(NULL, RT_MENU, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MENU),
    MAKELANGID(LANG_AFRIKAANS, SUBLANG_AFRIKAANS_SOUTH_AFRICA));
HGLOBAL hGlob = LoadResource(NULL, hRes);
LPVOID pData = LockResource(hGlob);

// create the menu
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenuIndirect((MENUTEMPLATE*)pData);
```

Comment: Small mistake in your code (2017-01-13): using [`FindResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `FindResourceEx()`. **Question:** is it unnecessary to destroy the previous menu like I did in my example code, before loading the new one?

Comment: @user7023624 *The SetMenu function replaces the previous menu, if any, but it does not destroy it. An application should call the DestroyMenu function to accomplish this task*